# Is it possible to search by date in "quarter"s in elasticsearch/lucene?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I made a date histogram facet by interval="quarter". It shows in my facet that there are 10 results for the quarter "2003-07". The question is how can I make a lucene query/search to get those documents? To search by date I usually do:

```
myquery AND (dateField: 2003-07)
```

How do I search by all documents within the quarter "2003-07" if able (preferrably in human readable lucene)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question mentions elasticsearch so I will answer within that context (although the question body only states 'lucene query').

An elasticsearch query to retrieve a date range is how I would approach it. For example

```
{"facets": {
  "keywords":{
    "terms":
      {"size":100,"field":"text"}
    }
  },
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "filter":{
        "range":{
          "created_at":{
            "from":"2013-07-01T00:00:00+00:00",
            "to":"2013-10-01T00:00:00+00:00"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

That would limit the results (and all your facets) to just that date range. Alternatively, remove the `"filtered": {"filter"` properties in order to have a straight query that does not impact the results of the facet.

Note, you may wish to take into account time zones as well.

Comment: That is a good way if there is no good way for users to type a simple string, which is what I am hoping exists... if it does.

Comment: Rolando, have you tried to use the query string query to perform your query? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/ If that works, then you can use it within a filter query to achieve the same result